# Using dc.js with data dimension in array

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have an array with the following data for each node

```
[{
    "id": "2130483",
    "appId": "SIGERprod",
    "time": 1500,
    "dateStart": 1521564131000,
    "timestamp": 1521564131000,
    "dateEnd": 1521564131000,
    "ipAddress": "10.110.11.111",
    "principalName": "suiza_2@hotmail.com",
    "contextPath": "/prueba",
    "ruta": "/prueba/xhtml/formasPreCodificadas/llenarForma.xhtml",
    "metodo": "POST",
    "status": 200,
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 3,
    "day": 20,
    "hour": 10,
    "minute": 42,
    "second": 11
}]
```

I have the following code and this code grouped my request per date

```
$.getJSON(prefix + "/getFullData.htm", {idApp: App, dateStart: inicio, dateEnd: fin},

        function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (d) {
                d.date = new Date(d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.minute, d.second, 0);

            });

            ndx = crossfilter(data);

            dateDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                return d.date;
            });

            var peticiones = dateDimension.group().reduceCount();
            var minDate = dateDimension.bottom(1)[0].date;
            var maxDate = dateDimension.top(1)[0].date;

            solicitudesXIntervalo
                    .width(1000)
                    .height(200)
                    .mouseZoomable(true)
                    .dimension(dateDimension)
                    .group(peticiones)                        
                    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
                    .yAxisLabel("request grouped by second");
```

and I get the following

[image: current output]

I need to graph the time it takes each request (time vs date)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the requests to be summed based on their durations rather than just counted.

If this is what you mean, it's a simple change:

```
        var peticiones = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
            return (d.dateEnd - d.dateStart) / 1000;
        })
```

I am dividing by 1000 to get seconds instead of milliseconds; adjust as needed.

However, in your example data above, the duration is 0 (and wouldn't show up at all). So I am not sure if I understand your question. Please comment and/or edit your question if I've missed the mark.